# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'cordova.exec') with Sencha Touch and Cordova 3.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm working on a POC project with Apache Cordova 3.0 and Sencha Touch 2.3. Things were working fine for a while but now whenever I attempt to invoke code in Cordova that calls down to my custom plugin it fails because of the error in the title.

I know for a fact that the onDeviceReady event is being fired because I listen for it and throw up an alert popup when it is received, and the alert fires every time.

Not sure what else to check or what other details to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - I was loading cordova.js explicitly in my index.html. But Sencha touch was also loading cordova.js explicitly in a non-obvious way(automatically specified in app.json). Once I removed my own cordova.js inclusion it loaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error explains that your custom plugin is not correctly configured in your app.

1) Have you included the custom plugin's js file in your page? Add the .js file after cordova.js and before using your custom plugin's feature.

2) How you have added the custom plugin to your project? Its always recommended to use the CLI tool to add/remove any plugin.

Comment: Does Cordova itself fail to load if one plugin is not configured correctly? 'cause this is telling me cordova itself is not loaded. In any case, I did add my plugin's js file to the page in the right spot, and it's in the project(confirmed it's in config.xml and copied to the correct location).

Comment: It happens.. Also you should see if you are using the correct version of the plugin code.. There are some major differences between cordova 2.* and 3.* plugins.

Comment: We developed the plugin specifically for 3.0 and we only support 3.0 so I don't think that's it.

Comment: I did a dump of the cordova object to the console. It is defined, but it doesn't show the exec function prototype as being defined. Weird.

Comment: You installted the cordova and plugin via node.js?

Comment: Cordova yes. The plugin is my own so no. But I triple checked all the settings since my last comment.

Comment: I reverted back to the latest code that I had pushed up that I knew for sure was working and still fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced the same problem. it seems that Adobe made a really mess in the move from 2.x to 3.x.

What I'm doing in my plugins is checking for cordova.exec and requiring it if not defined. For example, at very top source code of your plugin add the following:

```
 var cordova = require('cordova');
 cordova.exec = cordova.exec || require('cordova/exec');
```

This should do the trick.

Best regards,

Eric

Comment: Thanks. My problem was actually that Sencha was loading Cordova under the covers while I was trying to load it as well, which was causing the issue.